# Determine Position in Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to be able to find the position of a string in a column. I have an app where the user adds to a list which forms a card and when they swipe the card, it deletes. I'm new to SQLite and I'm having a bad time trying to delete the items I want.

Here's what I have so far:

```
c2.moveToFirst();
String contentLabel = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Content"));
db.delete("Lists", "Content = '" + contentLabel + "'", null);
```

Now the problem with this is that when I swipe the card away, say, on the third card, the first card gets removed and the card that was swiped away moves to the top of the list.

Comment: `c2.moveToFirst();` sets the cursor to the first item. You need to move it to the correct position.

Comment: Is there a moveTo method that moves it to the contentLabel position?

Comment: Of course there is...c2.moveToPosition().

Comment: If you know the content label of the card directly, you don't need to move, or even use the `Cursor`. Just use the label directly on the query... unless I misunderstood the objective.

Comment: `Is there a moveTo method` ... I don't know, did you check the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: really, this is simple and all you need is to do some research first instead of posting a thread

Comment: @mihail I did research but I think I was confused about the things I read...perhaps misunderstanding them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndrewT. I fixed it! Did this: `c2.moveToPosition(c2.getPosition());` Shall I delete this thread or would someone find it useful?

Comment: It's okay not to delete, but I find it weird to use `c2.moveToPosition(c2.getPosition());` since `getPosition()` returns current cursor position, and `moveToPosition()` move the cursor to that position. It's like `editText.setText(editText.getText());` in my opinion. If you remove the `move..()` at all, will it work?

Comment: @AndrewT. well, hmmm...interesting question. I just know that for now, it works. I'll look into it though.

Comment: @AndrewT. I did what you said and it turns out, the code I put ^^^ does not even fix it...it seemed to be fixed but it isn't. So, I'm right back to my same question.

Comment: Umm, let me clarify the question, since maybe I misunderstood the concept until now: you're basically using `ListView` (or similar) for the card container? Possibly, I need the full code of how you handle the swipe.

Comment: @AndrewT. if you have Google+, send me an invite: +Andrew Quebe...we can chat with Hangouts. I don't want to go into a large chat here because of SO guidelines.

Comment: You question is not clear at all. You should post relevant part of your code, especially the part related to the deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most accurate way to delete the correct item from the Sqlite database is by specifying the  unique ID of the item to be deleted.

Did you create your database with an _id column? If not you may be able to use Sqlite's default `ROWID` column instead - never tried it, but I believe that android automatically maps this to _id anyway. 
You must add the ID number to your loader's projection, so that you have this value in your cursor when you fill your card views with data.

Assuming that your list items - or cards - are using a custom layout, you should have an implementation of [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) which fills the cards with data by either recycling an existing view, or creating a new view for each list item that is displayed.

When you populate each list item with data, in the cursor adapter, you should also call `listItemView.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex('_id')));` on the card view. This will store the the associated Sqlite row id number in the card view. Which I believe is a Long.

In your item dismissed handler, you can then call `listItemViewToDismiss.getTag();` to learn the ID number that you want to delete from your database. Note that we've stored this as a String, but `View.getTag()` will return an Object, so this will need to be cast back to string, like so:

```
String storedRowId = (String) listItemViewToDismiss.getTag();
```

Once you have the database row ID easily reachable, the rest is simple:

```
db.delete(URI, "_id=?", new String[] { (String) cardViewToDismiss.getTag() });
```

This will delete only the rows which have the unique id specified in the list item's tag - if you're using SQLite's AUTOINCREMENT on your _id column - which I hope you are - then this should only ever delete one row, or zero rows if it has already been deleted by another process.

If your content provider can handle URIs to individual items, then I think you can also insert the full URI of the current item (with an appended ID) into the view's tag and then simply call

```
db.delete( (String) viewToDismiss.getTag() );
```

... and let the content provider delete the correct item.

**Some references**

Cursor Adapter's getView method:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html] (See getView() on that page)

Setting tags:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

**disclaimer**

It's been a while since I've done this, and I wrote that code from memory, so I hope someone will correct me if this is no longer the best practice for Android development, or if I've made a stupid error.

Comment: I'm using a listview for this...I tried the Long.toString(mListview.getTag()) and it gave me an error saying incompatable types (Long and Object).

Comment: Also, I'm not using an _id column so I added one because the "default" one was returning errors saying it did not exist.

Comment: `mListView.getTag()` implies that you're getting the tag on the whole list view. You should be getting the tag from the individual list item that is being dismissed. I'll try to update my answer to better explain.

Comment: When you use View.getTag(), you get back an Object, so this would need to be cast back to Long. In retrospect, maybe it would be more useful to handle it as a String from the beginning, assuming that you only ever insert it into a SQLite query as a String parameter. I'll see if I can add that to my answer, too.

Comment: Yeah I eventually figured it out and changed it accordingly. Nice, clean, straight-forward answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your code is now, you always delete the first item. Move your cursor to the element you want to delete, with the method `cursor.moveToPosition(int position)`.

Change your code to this:

```java
// position = position of the "swiped card" (e.g. for the third card position is 3)
c2.moveToPosition(position - 1); 
String contentLabel = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Content"));
db.delete("Lists", "Content = '" + contentLabel + "'", null);
```

`moveToPosition(int position)` returns false if it fails to move to the position (e.g. there is no such position), so you may want to add some code to check this:

```java
if (!c2.moveToPosition(position - 1)) {
    //failed to move!
}
String contentLabel = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Content"));
db.delete("Lists", "Content = '" + contentLabel + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help?

```
String cardLabel;    

card.setOnSwipeListener(new Card.OnSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipe(Card card) {
            lable = "[code to get the swiped card's text]"
        }
    });
    db.delete("Lists", "Content = '" + cardLabel + "'",    null);
```

Basically just add some type of listener to get the text of the card as it is swiped and delete where the text equals that found by the listener. The issue with deleting by the text could be that the user might have two cards with the same text, maybe accidentally added it twice, but when they try to remove the duplicate, this would delete both.

Querying this way with the user defined text might also open you up to sql injection. I'm not sure how or if Android has any mechanisms to handle that, but it's worth thinking about. I agree with the others saying the proper way would be to search by ID. If you wanted to do an ID automatically, you could add something like this to the CREATE TABLE SQL statement in your DB helper.

```
   Lists._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
```

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should use [ormLite](http://ormlite.com/) or [greenDao](http://greendao-orm.com/) and focus on your app and not fighting with sql.